# Understanding a Proof for the Prime Number Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-explanation, residue-calculus

Section 3.7. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* is about a proof for the PNT. The followings are the assumptions come in the text that I could not prove:

1- Define $g(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^x \dfrac{\pi(u) \log u}{u} du$ and $h(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^x \dfrac{g(u)}{u} du$. (a) How to show that $h(x)$ is continuous while $\pi(x)$ is a jump-function? (b) What does it mean $h(x)$ is of *bounded variation* in any finite interval?

2- Define $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \displaystyle\int_{c- i \infty}^{c + i \infty} \dfrac{x^s}{(s-1)s^2} ds + \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c- i \infty}^{c + i \infty} \dfrac{\psi(s)}{s^2} ds$, where $c > 1$. The book claims that the first term is equal to the sum of the residues on the left of the line $Re(s)=c$ and writes the result to be $x - \log x -1$. But I get $x - \log x$, $x$ for $s=1$ and $-\log x$ for $s=0$. Where does the extra $-1$ come from?

Note: $$\psi(s) = - \dfrac{1}{s-1} - \dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{s \zeta(s)} + \dfrac{\log \zeta(s)}{s^2} + \displaystyle\int_2^{\infty} \pi(x) \log x \dfrac{1 - 2 x^s}{x^{s+1}(x^s-1)^2} dx.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h$ is of bounded variation in $[a,b]$, $a>0$, if there exists a global bound $M$ such that for all partitions $a=c_0<c_1<c_2<\cdots<c_n=b$ we have: $\sum_{k=1}^n|h(c_k)-h(c_{k-1})|<M$. That $h$ is of bounded variation and (absolutely) continuous follows from the very simple bound $|\int_a^{x+h}f-\int_a^xf|\le h\cdot\sup_{t\in[x,x+h]}|f(t)|$ and the observation that the integrand of $h$, $g(u)/u$, is bounded on any finite *positive* interval $[a,b]$, $a>0$. That follows from boundedness of $g$ on any such interval, which is clear.

As for your second question the statement about the *first* integral equaling the sum of residues is not hard to justify, take a massive box contour to the left of $\{\Re s=c\}$ with one edge running $c-iN\to c+iN$ and limit in $N$. The integrands is suitably quickly vanishing on the remaining three edges (you can't do this for the second integral since the integrand is not analytic near $s=1$).

So it remains to calculate the residue at $s=0$ correctly. At $s=1$ we do just get $x$. At $s=0$, observe: $$\frac{x^s}{s-1}=-\exp(s\ln x)(1-s)^{-1}=-(1+s\ln x+o(s))(1+s+o(s))\\=-1-(1+\ln x)s+o(s)$$So $-(1+\ln x)$ is the correct residue at $s=1$. I believe you missed the fact $(s-1)^{-1}$ contributes to the residue.

Comment: Thanks! Second part is very clear. For the first part: $f(u)=g(u)/u$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and $|\int_a^{x+t}f-\int_a^xf|\le t\cdot\sup_{s\in[x,x+t]}|f(s)|$ holds. How do you conclude from those two that $h$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^n|h(c_k)-h(c_{k-1})|<M$ for any partition? $h$ being continuous is also clear from your explanation.

Comment: @Ali Note $\sum_{k=1}^n|h(c_k)-h(c_{k-1})|\le\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|=(b-a)\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|$. In fact, $h$ is Lipschitz on any such interval $[a,b]$ with Lipschitz constant $\sup_{t\in[a,b]}g(t)/t$. Lipschitz functions are (absolutely) continuous and of bounded variation by this argument

Comment: Well the problem is that how $\sum_{k=1}^n|h(c_k)-h(c_{k-1})|\le\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-c_{k-1})\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|h(t)|$?

Comment: Let me find a text that I can study from that and I will come back to you if still I have problem with it

Comment: @Ali Just because $|h(c_k)-h(c_{k-1})|\le|c_k-c_{k-1}|\sup_{t\in[c_{k-1},c_k]}|f(t)|\le(c_k-c_{k-1})\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|$

Comment: So you suppose continuity of h and its differentiability and use the MVT. For example see Example 3 in https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/variation.pdf . That way I non-rigorously suppose h is continuous because it is Riemann integral of piecewise continuous function

Comment: Sorry, what is f? Is it a typo? f=h? or f=h'? You didn't introduce f, and used h for interval as well. Do you suppose h to be continuous and differentiable to deduce bounded variation?

Comment: @Ali We do *not* need differentiability *or* the MVT. $f$ is a placeholder for the integrand, so, $f(t)=g(t)/t$. It does turn out that $h$ is differentiable but we don't need that.

Comment: For calculating residue I was using L'Hopital's rule!!

Comment: @Ali Be careful with doing that for higher order poles though! At $s=0$ we have a second order pole, so the correct limit expression (if you insist on using this method) would be $\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}[sf(s)]=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{x^s}{(s-1)s}$. Is this what you did?

Comment: I did $\lim_{s\to0} s f(s) = \lim_{s\to0} s \frac{x^s}{(s-1)s^2}$, and when I encountered $0/0$ I used L'Hopital's rule and I lost the term $-1$. But L'Hopital's rule has worked so far, and I now see that those were by chance!

Comment: @Ali If $f$ is a meromorphic function with $n$th order pole at $s=z$ then: $$\mathrm{Res}(f;z)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{s\to z}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}s^{n-1}}[(s-z)^nf(s)]$$But in practice this is not a very useful formula. In practice, working with Taylor and Laurent series directly is more effective

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help :)